# Analytic version of the Cartan lemma

Tags: smooth-manifolds, analytic-functions, differential-forms, real-analytic-structures

Assume that $\beta$ is a real analytic 2-form on an analytic manifold $M$ and $\alpha$ is an analytic non vanishing 1-form on $M$. Assume that $\beta \wedge  \alpha=0$. Is there an analytic 1-form $\gamma$ on $M$ with $\alpha \wedge  \gamma=\beta$?

This is needed in the following question:

[A cohomology associated to a 1- form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161572/a-cohomology-associated-to-a-1-form/161579#comment412666_161579)

Comment: Probably the easiest way to verify this is to choose local co-ordinates such that $\alpha = f\,dx^1$.

Comment: @DeaneYang But my question is  a global question. Since we search for an analytic solution we can not globalize using partition of unity

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: If there exists a global analytic vector field $v$ such that $\langle\alpha,v\rangle$ never vanishes, then $\gamma = i(v)\beta$ works.

Comment: @DeaneYang thanks for this point. Lets consider the particular case that $\alpha$ is   integrable distribution. so we have  a foliation. your statment is equivalent to "triviality of normal bundle to the foliation".since the smooth version of your stament is always true(by partition unity, we conclude that the normal bundle is  a trivial bundle as a smooth bundle. according to materials in Hirsch book diff topology(reconstruction of smooth structure to analytic one) conclude  this  normal bundle is  trivial as an analytic bundle. so it seems question is remain only for nonintegrable $\alpha$.

Comment: A more general condition is that there exists a global vector field $v$ such that $\gamma = i(v)\beta$ never vanishes.